# Transaction between contexts

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a Console Application using Entity Framework Core (7).

The application is divided into 3 different areas but the database is shared.
I created 3 different `DbContext` and now I need to perform a transaction between all of them.
So I need an atomic operation the save all the changes or nothing (rollback).

I know that in Entity Framework 6 there was a class called `TransactionScope` but I cant find an alternative in EF Core.

Using the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection("Server=x.x.x.x,1433;Database=test;user id=test;password=test;"))
        .Options;

        var cat = new Cat { Name = "C", Surname = "C", Age = 55 };
        var dog = new Dog { Date = DateTime.Now, Code = 120, FriendId = cat.Id };

        using (var context1 = new DogsContext(options))
        {
            using (var transaction = context1.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    context1.Dogs.Add(dog);
                    context1.SaveChanges();

                    using (var context2 = new CatsContext(options))
                    {
                        context2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
                        context2.Cats.Add(cat);
                    }

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteScalar requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(Boolean async, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean openConnection, Boolean closeConnection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
```

Comment: `TransactionScope` isn't implemented yet but afaik its coming in `netstandard2.0`, some time in 2017. But you can try the unit of work pattern

Comment: looking at your revised code example, you did not call context2.SaveChanges()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) is not part of Entity Framework. Its part of the System.Transactions namespace. Additionally, TransactionScope is not the [recommended approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) for handling transactions with Entity Framework 6.x.

With Entity Framework Core you can share a transaction across multiple contexts for relational databases only. The contexts must share the same database connection.

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#share-connection-and-transaction

Example:

```cs
using (var context1 = new YourContext())
{
    using (var transaction = context1.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // your transactional code
            context1.SaveChanges();
            
            using (var context2 = new YourContext())
            {
                // or pass the connection from context1 to the constructor of context2 with proper overload
                context2.Database.SetDbConnection(context1.Database.GetDbConnection());
                context2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
                // your transactional code
                context2.SaveChanges();
            }
            
            // Commit transaction if all commands succeed, transaction will auto-rollback when disposed if either commands fails
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you William. Is those example you are using YourContext twice. It does not work if you have something like UsersContext and OrderContext

Comment: My example is for the same context type, but you can also share a transaction across multiple context instances. According to the EF core documentation (see referenced link) - "You can also share a transaction across multiple context instances".

Comment: Using that code I get a transaction exception. I updated the open post with more details. Thank you