# EF-Core 5: IDbContextTransaction has no definition for "GetDbContextTransaction()". How do I use a different context properly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

My problem is, that I want to have operations on 2 DbContext objects (both scaffolded with `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` using a model first approach).

I'm dealing with an architecture, which needs to be modular, so I have a abstract base class, which can insert specific tables, which are always the same. Even the model and context is located in a global project, so every project can reference it directly.

what I'm trying is to begin a transaction, then call the base class to insert the base tables, which are always the same to the same transaction. After that I proceed to save the remaining operations, which differ from project to project.

Everywhere on the internet, even stackoverflow and msdn.com I find the aproach to save the transaction object returned by `context.Database.BeginTransaction()` and pass it to the second context with `context.Database.UseTransaction(tran.GetDbTransaction())`

*references:*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#share-connection-and-transaction
[Transaction between contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020221/transaction-between-contexts)

The problem is, that the compiler tells me, that the type returned by `BeginTransaction()` has no member called `GetDbTransaction()`

Just passing the returned object to `UseTransaction()` won't compile, since the compiler can't cast `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IDbContextTransaction` (returned by `BeginTransaction()` to `System.Data.Common.DbTransaction` (needed by `UseTransaction()`)

this error sounds so simple to me, but somehow I can't find anything on the internet to why my `IDbContextTransaction` does not have this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetDbTransaction()` is an extension method in the namespace `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage`, so you have to have a `using` declaration to bring the extension method in-scope.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
```

Comment: Beat me to it..:). A rather annoying aspect of using extension methods in different namespaces which the documentation never seems to mention when referencing methods like this..

Comment: @StevePy Really? It's the very first line in the method [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.dbcontexttransactionextensions.getdbtransaction?view=efcore-5.0)

Comment: I'm referring to the documentation like what the OP had posted that outlines how to implement transactions. There they clearly show an example that uses `.GetDbTransaciton()` without any mention that it is an extension method in another namespace you will have to reference. Intellisense can help you recognize this if you bother to type the whole method name in and it will pick up on adding the namespace, but for most newer devs, if Intellisense doesn't list it when they start typing, then the question comes up whether the doco is out of date, etc. A nuisance, nothing more, just more searching.

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot! I read the part about it being an extension method, but I didn't even know what that means. I've started C# a few months ago and I'm still not totally familiar with some of it's features (I'm coming from C++), so I just kind of ignored this extension method part, since the documentation didn't really told anything about it later on